# How to stop new lines being created when I want to edit the first line when the file has been created

Tags: vb.net

I have made some functions that run on a button click. It creates the file if it does not exist and writes to the first line "1" on the first write to the file, however when you click the button again, it moves that "1" down a line each time in the file.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
    Dim appData As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
Dim Lines As New List(Of String)
Public Function ReadConfigLines()
    If File.Exists(appData + "\example.txt") Then
        Lines.Clear()
        Lines.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(appData + "\example.txt").ToList)
    End If

End Function
Public Function WriteConfigLines()

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim c As Integer = 0
    Dim newlines As String = ""
    While i < Lines.Count()

        While i > c
            newlines = newlines + vbCrLf
            c = c + 1
        End While
        File.WriteAllText(appData + "\example.txt", newlines + Lines(i))
        newlines = ""
        c = 0
        i = i + 1
    End While
End Function

Private Sub btnAvatar1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAvatar1.Click
    PBPreview.Image = btnAvatar1.Image
    ReadConfigLines()
    Lines.Insert(0, "1")
    WriteConfigLines()

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your program is working correctly: the first time you run the loop you're setting newlines equal to "" + vbCrLF, which is just a newline. Then you are writing newlines + Lines(i), which is a newline followed by your 1.

Comment: @ale10ander thank you so much, i have got it now :)